# Umbraco macro - Displaying content in all nodes

Tags: xslt, macros, umbraco

I have a navigation bar in which all links are grabbed from Umbraco items (entered by the user). This navigation bar needs to be displayed on all pages. I tried inserting the items into the master template, but the links are not passed down to slave nodes. So, I'm assuming I need some sort of a macro which grabs the content and displays on all pages.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I answered a question about creating a multi-level XSLT navigation menu a while back:

[Create multilevel menu for umbraco using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099166/create-multilevel-menu-for-umbraco-using-xslt/4250176#4250176)

Perhaps that will get you going?

I think the key is that you need to get to the top of the content tree (home), then build the navigation.  Otherwise the nav will be based on where in the tree the current page is.